# seleccionar texto en firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, html-select

Estoy tratando de seleccionar un texto en un formulario con javascript, si utilizo this.select() en google chrome funciona perfectamente pero al usar mozilla firefox esto ya no funciona.

Funciona del siguiente modo, colocas un texto en el input y al pulsar en cualquier lado te lo selecciona y puede cambiar el texto.

```
inputForm.addEventListener("focusout", function (e) {
this.select();
});
```

He probado con focus() tambien en firefox pero no obtengo el mismo resultado que con google chrome, alguien sabe como se haría ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Al parecer la forma en que Mozilla implementa el evento `focusout` produce una [condición de carrera (*race condition*)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condici%C3%B3n_de_carrera) entre dicho evento y el método `select()`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una solución es escribir el método dentro de un [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), para que de esta forma la condición de carrera desaparezca y el método `select()` sea correctamente ejecutado luego de que el evento `focusout` finalice su proceso.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('text-box');
function selectText(inputElement) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    inputElement.select();
  }, 0);
  
}

input.addEventListener('focusout', e => selectText(input));
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text-box" size="20" value="Hello world!">
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Mauricio!! casi me vuelvo loca buscando la forma de poder hacer esto correctamente :)